# Typescript - defining a type which is based on other type while specifying a specific field value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm writing a Graphql API and defining types in typescript.
I would like these types to be enforced as they describe the API input.

I would like to know if I can do something like this:

```
enum ActionType {
  CREATE = 'create',
  DELETE = 'delete',
}

interface BaseAction {
  actionType: ActionType;
};

type DeleteAction = BaseAction & {  
  actionType: ActionType.DELETE;
  id: string;
};

type CreateAction = BaseAction & {  
  actionType: ActionType.CREATE
  data: string;
  secArg: number;
};
```

Where I have an interface BaseAction and other types inherit/implement it while specifying the relevant action type.

Is this something which is preferable to do? or there another way on achieving such a definition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) is what you're looking for (What you are doing should work too). You may also benefit from [exhaustive checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#exhaustiveness-checking) in your reduced function with a pattern like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code automatically detect the type of actions when you create for instance a `DeleteAction`, you can change your types to classes and implement the `BaseAction` interface. Something like this :

```
enum ActionType {
  CREATE = 'create',
  DELETE = 'delete',
}

interface BaseAction {
  actionType: ActionType;
};

class DeleteActionClass implements BaseAction {
   public readonly actionType: ActionType;
   public id:string;
   constructor(id:string){
     this.actionType = ActionType.DELETE;
     this.id = id;
 }
 }

 const myfunc = (deleteAction:DeleteActionClass)=>{
   console.log(deleteAction.actionType)
 }

 const deleteAction : DeleteActionClass =  new DeleteActionClass('5');
 myfunc(deleteAction) // it logs 'delete' in console
```

Comment: I get the actions as input in the API request, so I want the code to verify the input

Comment: I didn't get the problem in input exactly, Could you please describe more about it?

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't know about Graphql API, but one thing that I found out is that you want to use the types as inputs give the type to you. For example the input give you the `create` action and based on this action you want to do initialize the specific type?